# An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable on hidden element

Tags: angularjs

I have an element that conditionally appears that is required to be filled out when visible. (using ng-required)

However, when it is not visible, I'm getting the following error:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

How do I force ng-required to work ONLY if it element is visible.  I do not want to enter novalidate in the form, because if I do, when the element is visible, the validation does not occur.

Comment: If you're using ng-hide, have you considered using ng-if instead (which removes the element from the dom completely)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this, using a boolean for both `ng-show` and `ng-required`:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" ng-show="displayCondition" ng-required="displayCondition"/>
</form>
```

Good question - a lot of people do not realize that passing `false` into `ng-required` disables the directive.

Comment: The commenter's answer is also valid, but depends on if you want the key to be empty (my solution) or non-existent (his/hers)

Comment: Great answer of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it very easy with using ng-if instead of ng-show! Us only ng-if. When it is not visible the element is not in the code anymore. So the browser will not validate it.