# Angular2 - An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Tags: html, forms, angular

I get the (dreaded)

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

error on one of my angular components. Before I get into details - I know that there are MANY questions that address this problem so these are the things I have tried that have not worked for me:

- Many responses address `hidden`/`required` form controls (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020971/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable-on-hidden-element)). I have no form controls that I have designated as hidden or required
- Some responses address issues with `<fieldset>` and `required` controls (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644606/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable-without-any-required-or-h)). I don't use field sets, and again, no required inputs
- Many other responses (eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable)) indicate that adding `novalidate` to your `<form>` solves the issue. Tried, unsuccessful

The only form controls that I have in this component are the `<form>` itself with one `<input>` (or list/array of inputs). I am pretty much out of ideas for what else to try to get around the issue.

For reference:

```html
<theme-panel-header>Add/Remove Charges</theme-panel-header>

<theme-panel-body>
    <form name="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive min-height-5 max-height-5 margin-bottom-4">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-left">
                                        Available Monthly Charges
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let charge of availableMonthlyCharges; let i=index"
                                    (click)="availableChargeSelected(i, charge)"
                                    [ngClass]="{'selected-image': selectedCharge && charge.id === selectedCharge.id }">
                                    <td>
                                        {{charge.name}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr *ngFor="let charge of monthlyChargesToRemove; let i=index">
                                    <td>{{charge.name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive min-height-5 max-height-5 margin-bottom-4">
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-left">
                                        Assigned Monthly Charges
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="text-right">
                                        Amount
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let charge of assignedMonthlyCharges; let i = index"
                                    (click)="assignedChargeSelected(i, charge)"
                                    [ngClass]="{'selected-image': selectedAssignedCharge && charge.id === selectedAssignedCharge.id }">
                                    <td>
                                        {{charge.name}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        {{charge.amount}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr *ngFor="let charge of monthlyChargesToAdd; let i=index"
                                    (click)="chargeToAddSelected(i, charge)"
                                    [ngClass]="{'selected-image': selectedChargeToAdd && charge.id === selectedChargeToAdd.id }">
                                    <td>{{charge.name}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="number"
                                               class="form-control text-right"
                                               name="monthlyChargesToAdd{{i}}"
                                               [(ngModel)]="monthlyChargesToAdd[i].amount" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center col-md-offset-4">
                <div>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-default pad-left-3 pad-right-3"
                            [disabled]="!(selectedAssignedCharge || selectedChargeToAdd)"
                            (click)="removeFromAssignedCharges()">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>&nbsp; Remove
                    </button>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-default pad-left-6 pad-right-6"
                            (click)="addToAssignedCharges()"
                            [disabled]="!selectedCharge">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>&nbsp; Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-right pad-right-1">
                <button type="button" name="exitButton" class="btn btn-danger pad-left-3 pad-right-3" (click)="handleExit()">Exit</button>
                <button type="button" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" (click)="submit()">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</theme-panel-body>
```

Comment: I am just curious, why are you using interpolation here? `monthlyChargesToAdd{{i}}`

Comment: @jhhoff02 because I'm using *ngFor to generate a list of inputs, I used the interpolation so that each one would have a unique name. Not sure if it's necessary or if multiple inputs can have the same name?

Comment: They can have the same name because it's more like the name of the input itself, not dependent on the data. You could put something like `name="MonthlyCharge"`